# ¿Cómo usar promesas para .map() que contiene un update de mongoose?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongoose

Es una api con Node y express usando a mongoose como ORM para mongo. Quiero actualizar un campo Array de un modelo:

**models/channel.js**

Esquema:

```
const ChannelSchema = Schema({
  name: { type: String, default: 'Anonimo' },
  users: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Users',  unique: true }]
})
```

el atributo *users* es un array que contendrá objetos de tipo ObjectId que harán referencia a otro modelo llamado *Users* y los id deben ser únicos.

Entonces lo que quiero es insertar elementos en ese array pero tengo problemas a la hora de retornar una respuesta con el objeto *res*

En mis pruebas con postman estoy enviando este array:

```
users[]:591788547e397b0f44b85f3c
users[]:591788b372b8a100dc7941cb
```

**controllers/channel.js**

```
function addUsers (req, res) {
  const channelId = req.params.id
  const users = req.body.users

  if (!users || !users instanceof Array) return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Los usuarios deben llegar en forma de array' })
  if (!channelId) return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Debes enviar el id del canal' })

  const options = {safe: true, upsert: false, new: true}

  users.map((user) => {
    let update = { $addToSet: { 'users': user } }
    Channel.findByIdAndUpdate(channelId, update, options, (err, channelUpdated) => {
      if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: `Hubo un error: ${err}` })
      if(!channelUpdated) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Hubo un error' })
      res.status(200).send({ channelUpdated })
    });
  })
}
```

Funciona bien, sólo inserta los id's que no se repitan. El problema está en retornar la respuesta cuando todo sale bien ya que me tira:

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Aunque coloque

```
return res.status(200).send({ channelUpdated })
```

Me sigue arrojando error.

Entonces pensé en usar promesas para ello pero no he tenido éxito. El código lo modifiqué así:

```
function addUsers (req, res) {
  const channelId = req.params.id
  const users = req.body.users

  if (!users || !users instanceof Array) return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Los usuarios deben llegar en forma de array' })
  if (!channelId) return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Debes enviar el id del canal' })

  const options = {safe: true, upsert: false, new: true}

  const promises = users.map((user) => {
    let update = { $addToSet: { 'users': user } }
    return Channel.findByIdAndUpdate(channelId, update, options, (err, channelUpdated) => {
      if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: `Hubo un error: ${err}` })
      if(!channelUpdated) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Hubo un error' })
      resolve => channelUpdated
    });
  })

  Promise.all(promises)
  .then((channelUpdated) => {
    return res.status(200).send({ channelUpdated })
  })

}
```

Sin embargo, me retorna siempre lo siguiente, actualice o no actualice:

```
{
  "channelUpdated": [
    null,
    null
  ]
}
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Qué más quieres de mí, vida?

Comment: Tu error no radica en las promesas si no en los condicionales que envias mas de 1 vez el `res.status(n)`

Comment: Puedes probar poniendo un `console.log("Aqui esta el error")` en cada uno de los condicionales.

Comment: if (err) return res.status(500).send({ err }) >>> el return es para que se termine el script y por lo tanto no deberia de ejecutarse de nuevo. El error esta en el res.status(200)..... es ahí donde me tira el error.

Comment: @HectorSeguro lo que pasa es que en el .map() aunque coloque return res.status(200).send(channelupdated), en la segunda iteración es cuando trata de enviar de nuevo el status a pesar de que tenga un return. ¿Cómo debería ser entonces? :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Va un esquema de código a ver si te ayuda. Lo importante es:

1. hacer el `res.status` una sola vez (los headers hay que enviarlos antes de los datos
2. juntar todas las respuestas en un array de resultados para luego enviar todo junto
3. esas respuestas que sean una promesa

Vamos con el esquema de la solución (lo importante es la idea, quizás haya que arreglar un poco la sintaxis):

```
const promises= users.map((user) => {
  let update = { $addToSet: { 'users': user } }
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ 
    Channel.findByIdAndUpdate(channelId, update, options, (err, channelUpdated) => {
      if (err) return reject(err); 
      if(!channelUpdated) return reject(new Error('Error desconocido')); 
      return resolve(channelUpdated);
    });
  });
});
// aquí promises es un array de promesas
Promise.all(promises)
.then((results) => {
  // envía el arreglo todas las respuestas. Todas pasaron
  return res.status(200).send(results); 
}).catch((err) => {
  // hubo alguna respuesta. Informo.
  return  res.send(500).send(`hubo un error ${err.message}`);
});
```

Comment: Gracias, era lo que me faltaba